# Using container log4j.properties file not able to read from ENV file which has passed while container startup using env.list file

Tags: environment-variables, containers, log4j, wildfly

Once i started container using env.list, this env.list file contain the value as:
ROOTCATEGORY=DEBUG, CONSOLE

But once i start the wildfly using log4j.properties using below syntax one by one. none of
them are able to fetch the value form ENV variable(ROOTCATEGORY).

Below syntax i tried but none of them is replacing the value of log4j.properties. i have
tried one by one only not all or multiple together.

```
log4j.rootCategory=${env.ROOTCATEGORY}
log4j.rootCategory="${env.ROOTCATEGORY}"
log4j.rootCategory=${env:ROOTCATEGORY}
log4j.rootCategory="${env:ROOTCATEGORY}"
log4j.rootCategory=${sys.ROOTCATEGORY}
log4j.rootCategory="${sys.ROOTCATEGORY}"
log4j.rootCategory=${sys:ROOTCATEGORY}
log4j.rootCategory="${sys:ROOTCATEGORY}"
log4j.rootCategory=$ROOTCATEGORY
log4j.rootCategory="$ROOTCATEGORY"
log4j.rootCategory=${ROOTCATEGORY}
log4j.rootCategory="${ROOTCATEGORY}"
log4j.rootCategory=$"{ROOTCATEGORY}"
log4j.rootCategory=$"{env.ROOTCATEGORY}"
log4j.rootCategory=$"{env:ROOTCATEGORY}"
log4j.rootCategory=$"{sys.ROOTCATEGORY}"
log4j.rootCategory=$"{sys:ROOTCATEGORY}"
```

please suggest how to set using container mode and retrieve the value of ROOTCATEGORY inside
log4j.properties file.

log4j.properties file is not able to read env variable inside container.

Answer (score 0):

You could set it as a system property and do it that way. In CLI you could do something like this:

```
/system-property=log4j.rootCategory:add(value=${env.ROOTCATEGORY})
```

Then in your `log4j.properties` you just have:

```
log4j.rootCategory=${log4j.rootCategory}
```

Comment: can you please tell where this command need to add:
/system-property=log4j.rootCategory:add(value=${env.ROOTCATEGORY})

in env.list file?

Comment: the same i want to do on Linux/Debian machine. please suggest.

Comment: That example is a command for the command line interface, `$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh`, in WildFly. You can set the system property in the web console too.

Comment: i have tried the same in my $JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh file to define as 
system-property=log4j.rootCategory:add(value=${env.ROOTCATEGORY})
but this is the way it is not working. Even start to wildfly is going on. please suggest.

Comment: Are you setting the environment variable?

Comment: yes i am setting environment variable and it was set already.. but not able to retrieve using above syntax.

Comment: It definitely worked for me locally. I'm not sure what else it could be.